# Printdocument Lines Overflowing Issue

Tags: c#, printdocument

I'm getting output with printdocument in C# form, there is no problem in richtextbox and it goes to the bottom line while writing but not when printing, how can I pass the overflowing text to the bottom line?

[image]

Comment: [Getting WYSIWYG Print Results from a .NET RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms996492(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: You should post your code, it's much easier to determine what is wrong. -- If you set `.OriginAtMargins = true`, in PrintDocument add `var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, e.MarginBounds.Width, e.MarginBounds.Height);` and use this rectangle as the print area when you call `Graphics.DrawString()`

Comment: If you instead want to add an interline to the paragraphs, you have to measure line per line (with `Graphics.MeasureString()`) using the same rectangle, get the height of the text paragraph, add an interline (based on the Font height (`Font.GetHeight()`) and offset the rectangle of these calculated measures for the next paragraph.